# Is there a fundamental reason there are two distinct types of energy?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, potential-energy

There are many forms of energy commonly encountered in physics: chemical, thermal, sound, electromagnetic, nuclear, gravitational, etc. But if you drill down, they are all either:

1. Energy of motion - Kinetic Energy
2. Energy of position - Potential Energy,

just at different scales. Is there a more "fundamental" reason why energy has this bimodal nature?

Comment: There is also energy in the electromagnetic fields, which isn't quite kinetic or potential

Comment: @OfekGillon Isn't that just electric potential energy (voltage), or are you talking about something else?

Comment: Not really, its energy in the fields themselves.

Comment: If the emphasis  is not on two (but on different) you might want to remember that energy is 'the thing which  is conserved with time" (cf Noether) so writing it has a sum of things allows you to take into account that while globally conserved the different forms transform one into the other (cf Lavoisier: Nothing is lost, nothing is created, everything is transformed).

Comment: @OfekGillon Isn't that still potential energy, just not tied to the position of a particle? It is possibly more commonly seen as potential energy when you have magnetic fields in electric inductors, but still.

Comment: @Arthur well, it's complicated and I think this is more of a terminological case. Most of the time, potential energy is an outcome of an integral of a force (times distance), something which doesn't correspond to the case you described. However, some people do consider it to be potential energy. Nevertheless, the energy of an electromagnetic wave isn't usually considered to be potential energy, although the energy is still contained in the fields themselves...

Answer (score 20):

Rob's answer is fine, but there are other perspectives.

First, note that potential energy is an abstract concept that doesn't cut it in general: Energy (or rather stress-energy-momentum) is the source of gravity, so we need to know exactly where it is located. In case of a system of electric charges, it's contained in the electromagnetic field. The difference in potential energy between two distinct arrangements of charges is the difference of the energy densities of the electromagnetic fields, integrated over all of space.

Kinetic energy then comes in because energy is not a scalar quantity, but the projection of energy-momentum onto the time axis of an observer. In some cases, it's possible to assign a rest frame to particular blobs of energy. We call energy measured from that frame 'mass'.

This description isn't entirely complete, as gravitational energy is a more subtle issue I'm happy to skip over in this particular answer.

Comment: Agreed. To apply the logic in my answer to a field theory would be a non-trivial task.

Comment: `In some cases, it's possible to assign a rest frame to particular blobs of energy. We call energy measured from that frame 'mass'.`  This is really a key point.  A good visualization for OP of how mass can be seen as an emergent property of systems of massless energetic particles : [PBS Space Time : The True Nature of Matter and Mass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSKzgpt4HBU)

Answer (score 19):

You are partitioning energies into

- energies associated with motion
- energies which are independent of motion

In a system governed by linear second-order differential equations like $m\ddot{\mathbf x} = \mathbf F(\mathbf x, \mathbf v) $, your system is *entirely specified* by positions and velocities. If you have energy remaining when the velocity vanishes, position is the only dynamical variable remaining.

Except mass --- which has its own associated energy, the intrinsic energy $mc^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would this reasoning also extend to a more modern theory, e.g. quantum mechanics or general relativity?

Comment: The Schroedinger equation, and other Hamiltonian-based models, basically start from an assumption that energy can be described by kinetic and potential energies, so the logic there is a little circular. Field theories, including classical EM and (probably) GR, require a little more careful thought.

Comment: I worry slightly that the distinction is less clear cut. Unless I am mistaken the Hamiltonian (Energy) for a charged particle in a magnetic field contains a part that depends on both the position and momentum of the particle. I don't think that part of the energy can be classified cleanly as either kinetic or potential.

Comment: The energy in mass can also be traced to potential energies - e.g. the strong nuclear binding energy that gives most of the mass of the nucleons.

Comment: The energy in mass can as well be traced to kinetic energies of all the particles constantly moving. Also, binding energies of any binding interaction are generally negative and subtract from the mass of the constituents. And then again, separating a potential and kinetic energy in the quantum world is a risky business.